# Objective-C streaming-upload audio

Tags: iphone, objective-c, node.js, audio, heroku

I'm looking for a way on an iPhone device to "stream upload" audio to a Heroku Node.js server.  In a sense, the user would hit "record" and it would open up a POST to the Node.js server, and Node.js would process the audio stream as it came in.

Does anyone know if this is possible (using NSURLConncetion), and if so could you lead me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may upload it Asynchronously, record it completely ,then fully upload it after

or just [NSStream](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server)  or pure TCP Socket as in unix and i use [cocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option (not using NSURLConnection)

http://debuggable.com/posts/streaming-file-uploads-with-node-js:4ac094b2-b6c8-4a7f-bd07-28accbdd56cb